# family of functions that satisfy $g(x^y+z)=g(x)^y +z$

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Is there a family of functions $g(x)$ or a form for g in which the following statement

$$g(x^y + z) = g(x)^y +z$$

is verified, with {x,y,z} in $\mathbb{R}$?

*Disclaimer*: This question came to my mind without any *background* so I'm not sure if it has a proper solution or not.

Comment: There is a problem with $x^{y}$ when $x <0$.

Comment: $g(1+z)=(g(1))^{y}+z$ so $g(z)=c+z$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Also $g(x^2) = g(x)^2$. Combined with the previous remark one must take $c=0$. So it is simply the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kavi Rama Murthy said you must suppose $x \geqslant 0$. Then by setting $x=1$ and $c=g(1)-1$, you have $g(z)=c+z$. Now continue by what @TokenToucan said and you have $c=c^2+2cx$, that must be satisfied for any $x$, which results in $c=0$, equivalents to $g(1)=1$, and in general $g(x)=x$. Notice that at the end there is no restriction like $x \geqslant 0$, and $x$ can get any real value.